# How to print variable value always as last column in CSV file

Tags: bash, parsing, awk

I have a list of CSV files, I have to print a variable name (dynamically; it will change), to last column in the CSV files.

Here is the code:

```
addProgramtypeID () {
    for csv in $1
    do
        file_name="$csv"
        echo $file_name
        f=`echo $file_name | cut -d '_' -f3 | cut -d '.' -f1`
        echo $f
        k=`grep -i $f Program_type.csv | cut -d ',' -f3`
        echo $k
        awk '{ print $0 "," "'"$k"'" }' "$csv" > tempfile && mv tempfile "$csv"
    done
}

addProgramtypeID "T_H_EDCGO.csv"
```

As of now the variable value `K` is being printed at the 1st column of the CSV file , also it is removing the first 2 characters of the first column in the file. My requirement is that the variable value should always come as the last column in the CSV file.

input :

```
TX_ID,SEQUENCE,PROGRAM_ID,CA_ID,C_ID
123,3,334,234,3
545,2,444,456,5
```

if suppose $k=2
output:

```
TX_ID,SEQUENCE,PROGRAM_ID,CA_ID,C_ID,2
123,3,334,234,3,2
545,2,444,456,5,2
```

Program_type.csv

```
type,desc,id
EDC,Alb,1
EDG,Gsc,2
```

Comment: Please give an expected output and the corresponding (trivial) input. Your description is hard to understand without example. I understand that you want to add the `$k` variable at the end of every lines. Is this correct?

Comment: Yes exactly $k value should be included in the last column.

Comment: Your script has too many errors (I count more than 1 bug per line on average) to use as a starting point, let's just start from some sample input and expected output. Please post a SMALL sample of both Program_type.csv and T_H_EDCGO.csv, and the expected output from running a tool on those files.

Comment: `sed "s/\$/,$k/" file.csv`?

Comment: Thanks a lot for the comment. This works similar to my code, does not give the end result

Answer (score 0):

It looks like what you want is just:

```
$ cat tst.sh
addProgramtypeID () {
    csv="$1"
    awk -v csv="$csv" '
    BEGIN{ FS=OFS=","; split(csv,csvA,/[_.]/); f=csvA[3] }
    NR==FNR { if ($0 ~ f) { k = $3 }; next }
    { print $0, k }
    ' Program_type.csv "$csv" > tempfile && mv tempfile "$csv"
}

addProgramtypeID "T_H_EDC.csv"

$ cat Program_type.csv
type,desc,id
EDC,Alb,1
EDG,Gsc,2

$ cat T_H_EDC.csv
TX_ID,SEQUENCE,PROGRAM_ID,CA_ID,C_ID
123,3,334,234,3
545,2,444,456,5

$ ./tst.sh

$ cat T_H_EDC.csv
TX_ID,SEQUENCE,PROGRAM_ID,CA_ID,C_ID,1
123,3,334,234,3,1
545,2,444,456,5,1
```

but it's hard to tell since your posted sample input could not produce your posted desired output so I had to make some up.

`if ($0 ~ f)` should probably just be `if ($1 == f)`, I just copied what your original `grep f <file>` logic would do.

Comment: Thanks for the comment Ed. But my issue still exists.

Comment: I suspect you create one or both of your input files in Windows and so MS have kindly placed control-Ms for free at the end of every line which is what's messing you up. Try `cat -v` to see them and then `dos2unix` to remove them then try the solution again. If that's not it then clarify what "my issue still exists" means.

Comment: Hi Ed, My input i.e "T_H_EDCGO.csv" is placed on the unix machine. (not in windows). I am trying to do a look up into Program_type.csv file from my input file and wan the desired output as I have given in my question. The $k variable should be printed in the last column of the csv file, which is currently not happening. This is the issue. Please let me know if this clarifies.

Comment: @user2376510 - no, see my comment, try my suggestions, and fix your sample input so it could produce your desired output.

Comment: @user2376510 I updated my answer to use my own sample input so you can see the script working the way I think you want. Again, though, given that you have characters vanishing, you almost certainly have control-Ms in your input file that you need to remove as I suggested earlier.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming there is is nothing nasty in your CSV file, you can use `awk` as follows:

```
for csv_file in $ALL_MY_FILES
do
    cat csv_file | awk 'BEGIN{FS=","}; {print($(NF))}'
done
```

Or even just

```
    cat $ALL_MY_FILES |  awk 'BEGIN{FS=","}; {print($(NF))}'
```

Both of these will print the last line column of all the csv files.  The results from each CSV are just appended together (is that really what you want?).

The difficulties are on the `awk` side.  This completely unaware of things like quited strings
or extra whitespace.  My recommendation is to try the line above, see what goes wrong (if anything) and then start tweaking.

Comment: Hi Adrian, I am noob in shell scripting. Please provide me little detailed answer. Thanks

Comment: Adrian, Thanks a lot. I just figured out the result set is coming correctly as I wanted, but when I see it on the Putty client it looks different(i.e as if the $k value is not coming as last column). I used the script which ypu posted to get the last column then I figured out code was fine. But when I import this csv file data into SQL table , there is the problem , only one row is getting imported that too with all zero values. !!!!

Comment: Change `cat file | awk 'script'` to `awk 'script' file`. Get rid of the semi-colon after your BEGIN section. Get rid of the parens around NF. Get rid of the parens around $NF. Use `while IFS= read -r csv_file` instead of `for csv_file in`.

Comment: I agree with these comments (if you are writing a script file).  And I am amazed it even work for me with those parens around NF.

Comment: @AdrianRatnapala you can add as many parens as you like around any variable in any context and the code will continue to work, it just obfuscates the code and makes people reading it waste their time trying to figure out why they're there.

Comment: It's there because of makefile induced paranoia by a coder who is only passing fluent in awk.  I read the manual once, back in the days that texinfo docs came standard with Linux distro.  Since then, not much.